# Bin the pandas data frame horizontally with bins=0.2 (fraction), how should I go about it?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, binning

I want to bin the data horizontally in a color-magnitude plane of stars. Here is how my data (red giant stars) look like:
[RGB stars in my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM1Mz.png)

Now, I want to bin these stars in small bins (bins = 0.2 or 0.3) horizontally i.e. parallel to the given X-axix. The number I am using for bins, as you can see, is not an integer.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
f814w = RGB_stars['col42'] # These are the stars I want to bin 
f814w_cut = pd.cut(f814w, bins=0.2) # using pd.cut with bins=0.2
```

This gives me an error:

"ValueError: `bins` should be a positive integer."

Another method I tried was df.sample from pandas, but I don't think it's working correctly for the data sample that I am working with. The output I obtain when I use this method is in random order, so I could not find a way to make sure if the splitting was done in the small bins (bins = 0.2 or 0.3).

What should I do to bin the entire column in number of bins < 1? Is there a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `bins=0.2` do you mean you want the **bin width** to be 0.2?

Comment: YYYesss, each \textbf{bin width} should be of 0.2 (magnitudes, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

`bins` is specifying the number of bins that you want to use. Therefore it has to be an integer. Looking at your data, bins of size `0.2` would give about 15 bins. You can specify this in 2 ways:

I’m starting with random values that somewhat look like your `f814w` series:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f814w
0    4.5
1    2.4
2    3.6
3    2.1
4    2.6
5    2.5
6    3.1
7    2.7
8    4.9
9    4.0
Name: col42, dtype: float64
```

Either compute the number of bins:

```
>>> bins = np.ceil((f814w.max() - f814w.min()) / .2)
>>> pd.cut(f814w, bins=int(bins))
0      (4.3, 4.5]
1      (2.3, 2.5]
2      (3.5, 3.7]
3    (2.097, 2.3]
4      (2.5, 2.7]
5      (2.3, 2.5]
6      (2.9, 3.1]
7      (2.5, 2.7]
8      (4.7, 4.9]
9      (3.9, 4.1]
Name: col42, dtype: category
Categories (14, interval[float64]): [(2.097, 2.3] < (2.3, 2.5] < (2.5, 2.7] < (2.7, 2.9] < ... <
                                     (4.1, 4.3] < (4.3, 4.5] < (4.5, 4.7] < (4.7, 4.9]]
```

Or specify the bin edges (which I find easier):

```
>>> pd.cut(f814w, bins=np.arange(f814w.min(), f814w.max() + .2, .2))
0    (4.3, 4.5]
1    (2.3, 2.5]
2    (3.5, 3.7]
3           NaN
4    (2.5, 2.7]
5    (2.3, 2.5]
6    (2.9, 3.1]
7    (2.5, 2.7]
8    (4.7, 4.9]
9    (3.9, 4.1]
Name: col42, dtype: category
Categories (15, interval[float64]): [(2.1, 2.3] < (2.3, 2.5] < (2.5, 2.7] < (2.7, 2.9] < ... <
                                     (4.3, 4.5] < (4.5, 4.7] < (4.7, 4.9] < (4.9, 5.1]]
```

This gives the exact same result. Note the `+ .2` on the high bound of `np.arange()` as it excludes the high bound when generating numbers, just like `range()`. If you can replace `f814w.min()` and `f814w.max()` with more theoretical or at least estimated bounds, then the second option (specifying bins) works better:

```
>>> pd.cut(f814w, bins=np.arange(2, 5.2, .2))
0    (4.4, 4.6]
1    (2.2, 2.4]
2    (3.4, 3.6]
3    (2.0, 2.2]
4    (2.4, 2.6]
5    (2.4, 2.6]
6    (3.0, 3.2]
7    (2.6, 2.8]
8    (4.8, 5.0]
9    (3.8, 4.0]
Name: col42, dtype: category
Categories (15, interval[float64]): [(2.0, 2.2] < (2.2, 2.4] < (2.4, 2.6] < (2.6, 2.8] < ... <
                                     (4.2, 4.4] < (4.4, 4.6] < (4.6, 4.8] < (4.8, 5.0]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cimbali, I now have a follow-up question. 
I used the second method on my data frame and I am getting repeated values like this:  

0      (15.644, 15.844]
1      (16.444, 16.644]. # This
2      (16.844, 17.044]. # This and the row below
3      (16.844, 17.044]
4      (17.044, 17.244]
             ...       
Name: col42, Length: 129, dtype: category
Categories (24, interval[float64]): [(15.444, 15.644] < (15.644, 15.844] < (15.844, 16.044] < (16.044, 16.244] ... (19.444, 19.644] < (19.644, 19.844] < (19.844, 20.044] < (20.044, 20.244]]

Any reason that's happening? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I want each bin width to be the size of 0.2 (magnitudes). But pd.cut() gives me the difference between two consecutive data points as 0.2.

Comment: @ShalmaleeKapse binning takes values and assigns them to bins, so bins might repeat indeed, if you have several points with in the same 0.2-interval. I’m not sure I understand your second point but try to edit it into your question